# Why isn't scalac [scala compiler] generating all of the necessary class files?

Tags: scala, maven, compilation, sbt

I am trying to get a simple Scala project to build using a proprietary build tool, called [Please](https://please.build). What it does is effectively calls `scalac` on my source files to build the appropriate files and then packages them together. Unfortunately, I discovered that it was missing some necessary class files, so I started experimenting by calling `scalac` directly myself.

I have the project building properly with both Maven and SBT. Here is the code for my main class:

```
package com.mypackage

case class Config(input: String = null)

object Main {

  val parser = new scopt.OptionParser[Config]("testapp") {
    arg[String]("input") action { (x, c) => c.copy(input = x) } text("input value")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    parser.parse(args, Config()) map { config =>
      val input = config.input
      println("input value is " + input)
    } getOrElse {
        System.exit(1)
    }
  }
}
```

I noticed that under the `src/main/scala/com/myproject` folder, both Maven and SBT will generate the following eight class files:

- Config.class
- Config$.class
- Main$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.class
- Main$$anon$1.class
- Main$$anonfun$main$1.class
- Main$$anonfun$main$2.class
- Main.class
- Main$.class

But when I call `scalac` directly, it only generates the following five classes:

- Config.class
- Config$.class
- Main$$anon$1.class
- Main.class
- Main$.class

Of course, with missing class files, I immediately run into runtime errors when trying to invoke the resultant JAR file. But I'm not sure what SBT or Maven are doing differently to compile that code. Even with the `-verbose` flag, Maven is still kind of a black box - I don't have any insight into what subprocesses it may be invoking. SBT on the other hand does have an option to run `export compile` and that's what I did. Strangely, though, when I run the *exact same* `scalac` command that is reported in SBT's export file, it still only builds five of the eight class files.

Does anyone here know much about Scala compilation? Are there some flags I need to pass to `scalac` that I'm missing? I can post the exact `scalac` invocation that I'm using if that will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using two different versions of Scala.

It looks like you have Maven and sbt set up to use Scala 2.11 which generates the extra anonymous classes, but the command-line `scalac` must be Scala 2.12 (if not 2.13) which uses JVM lambdas instead.

Comment: Interesting. When I search for all binaries named `scalac` on my system and invoke them with `/path/to/scalac -version`, each of them prints out `2.12.8`. So what is SBT/Maven using? I don't see the 2.11 version of scalac on my system. Is there some hidden flag you can pass to scalac to compile in an "older version" mode or somesuch?

Comment: In sbt there is the `scalaVersion` key that you can use to set the version for your projects.  So, add `scalaVersion := "2.12.8"` in `build.sbt`.